# Javascript loop doesn't work in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should work but its not. What am I doing wrong? I want to output "selected" to  tags I have on a meteor page

```
Template.editor.onRendered( function() {
var cats = ["Comedy","Action","Self Help"];
var arrayLength = cats.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if(cats[i].indexOf(getDocument.category) != -1){
        //found
        var id = cats[i].trim().toLowerCase();
        $("body").find("#"+id).attr("selected=selected");
        console.log(id);
    } else {
        console.log(getDocument.category)
    }
}
}
```

also

```
getDocument.category = ["Action", "Comedy"]
```

Comment: What are you getting in your console? Also, what's the point of calling `.trim()` on `cats[i]` since your array doesn't contain any rogue spaces and why not just store the cats as lower case values, so you don't have to call `.toLowerCase()` either?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe change

```
$("body").find("#"+id).attr("selected=selected");
```

with

```
$("body").find("#"+id).attr("selected","selected");
```

Edit:

```
if(cats[i].indexOf(getDocument.category) != -1){
```

I think you have here a wrong direction
try this instead:

```
if(getDocument.category.indexOf(cats[i]) != -1){
```

Comment: still not working but thanks for pointing that out. that was another bug

Comment: I literally just realised this, then I saw your comment. Thanks

Comment: Yes it did though I cant mark it as an answer due to lack of rep

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a line to set selected attribute

```
$("body").find("#"+id).attr("selected","selected");
```

Or try the following:

```
$(document).find("#"+id).attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: still not working but thanks for pointing that out. that was another bug

Answer (score 0):

If I do not mistakenly understand what you asking for, you are trying to find the elements of 'cats' array if exist in the getDocument.category. If so, the above approach is wrong. Take a look at this line:

```
if(cats[i].indexOf(getDocument.category) != -1){...}
```

the result of this `if checking` will always returning -1, the explanation is below:

`cats[i]` will return the element (with index i) of cats, so if i=0 the result will be "Comedy". Then, `indexOf` will be executed on it, `"Comedy".indexOf()` ,
to find the position of getDocument.category (which is an array).

That's means you are looking for an array inside a string? that's will not work.

Actually, we can check if an element exists in array with **includes** methods. So maybe the complete code will be looked like this:

```
Template.editor.onRendered(function() {
    var cats = ["Comedy", "Action", "Self Help"];
    var arrayLength = cats.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (getDocument.category.includes(cats[0])) {
            //found
            var id = cats[i].trim().toLowerCase();
            $("body").find("#" + id).attr("selected=selected");
            console.log(id);
        } else {
            console.log(getDocument.category)
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this will help, thanks